# Floating label with react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Im trying to do floating label like in this example but with react-bootstrap:

[Working example](https://codepen.io/peiche/pen/xOVpPo)

My Component at the moment:

```
<FormGroup controlId="email" bsSize="large">
        <FloatingLabel ref={this.floatingEmail}>Email</FloatingLabel >
        <FormControl
          autoFocus
          type="email"
          value={this.state.email}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </FormGroup>
```

Comment: You can have a look at this library as an example [react-styled-floating-label](https://github.com/ihor/react-styled-floating-label).

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but if this isn't quite what new people googling this want, give this library a look: https://github.com/brennanwilkes/react-bootstrap-floating-label

Answer (score -1):

React bootstrap 5.0 has the floating label

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-floating-labels